# Is Poke Milkweed nice or nasty?

Tags: perennials

I am growing this from seed:  [Asclepias exaltata](http://ontariowildflowers.com/main/species.php?id=85)  which is not the poisonous [pokeweed](http://www.altnature.com/gallery/pokeweed.htm)

Poke Milkweed   Height .5-1.5m  Zone: 4

The grower, [Gardens North](http://gardensnorth.com/site/), claims it is:

> Found in the wild in rich woods and forest edges, with elegant sprays
>   of long-lasting white flowers overlaid with a subtle lavender to green
>   tint. Poke milkweed is a species of the Carolinian forest, at the
>   northern limit of its range in southern Ontario.

Some milkweeds can be invasive. Has anyone grown this?

Comment: Can you trust the grower? Can you sure it is Asclepias exaltata? Sometimes the plant doesn't fit the description and the shop has no idea of the difference between species.

Comment: Yes, I trust the grower, Gardens North.  They have been in business for many years and I have bought seed from since they started their business from their kitchen table. However their plant descriptions are short. Vigorous for one person is invasive for another.

Comment: And neither plant are what I know as "milkweed". A wild annual that Monarch butterflies reportedly like for laying eggs.

Comment: Sounds like a garden for Monarch - http://www.minnesotawildflowers.info/flower/poke-milkweed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have no experience in planting this.

It is not listed under the invasive species specified on [U.S. Invasive Weed list](http://plants.usda.gov/java/invasiveOne), unlike some other milkweed you can find within the genius of Asclepias in that list.

And given the fact that it like partial-shade more than full sun, it might not be a fast growing plant.

Moreover, it is a heaven for monarch butterfly so you can save wildlife too. Though you plant might be chewed down to stem only during active growing season of monarch larvae.